# How to change transitions on Wordpress slider?

Tags: slideshow

I am using the Plixus Wordpress theme on a website at www.LenhamSportsCars.com.

You can see that there are different transitions for each slide, however I want them all to have the same transition which should be the one that slides the box across from side to side.

I have looked through all of the settings and there seems to be no settings that allow you to amend this so I am guessing I would need to play with the code, but do not know what to change.

Here is the index.php code that has the slider info on:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Granit
 */

get_header(); ?>

<script src="/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>



<?php $s_check = of_get_option('slide_check', '' ); 
if($s_check != "1") : ?>
<div class="wrapper theme-granit">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<?php $image1 = of_get_option('image_1', '' ); 
if($image1 != "") : ?>
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('image_1_url', '' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image1 ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $image2 = of_get_option('image_2', '' ); 
if($image2 != "") : ?>
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('image_2_url', '' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image2 ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $image3 = of_get_option('image_3', '' ); 
if($image3 != "") : ?>
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('image_3_url', '' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image3 ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $image4 = of_get_option('image_4', '' ); 
if($image4 != "") : ?>
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('image_4_url', '' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image4 ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $image5 = of_get_option('image_5', '' ); 
if($image5 != "") : ?>
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('image_5_url', '' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image5 ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
 </div> 
</div> <!-- end wrapper slider -->
<?php endif; ?>


<?php $hd = of_get_option('home_desc', '' ); 
if($hd != "") : ?>
<h2 id="welcome"><?php echo $hd; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>


<div class="wrapper">
<h6>

<br>
Andrew Actman and Ian Langford have joined forces at Lenham Sports Cars Ltd. 
Back at Harrietsham after a few years break we are ready to look after
your classic car and will undertake work ranging from servicing , pre MOT
checks, full restorations and preparation for racing, rallying and
touring.
<br><br>
Together we have many years of experience and have achieved considerable
motor sport successes including championship wins in the Austin Healey
Championship, the Midget Challenge and international rally victories. We
have also provided mechanical assistance in trans continental events.


</h6>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Well, i found it.

You go to wp-content/themes/plixus/js/ and open the file init.js. There you should find the following code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect:'fold,fade,boxRandom,sliceUpDown',
controlNav:false});
});
```

Now you can change the argument "effect" to whatever you like, like

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect:'fade',
controlNav:false});
});
```

That should do the trick.

---

Well, as it's a Nivo Slider which is used, there should be some option to set the Animation type (most likely set to "random" right now). Take a look at the theme options in the backend.

Comment: I have looked through all of the theme options. There is an option to turn the slider on or off and add the slides, but there is nothing to change the transitions. I'm 100% certain of that, been through it all many, many times.

Comment: Updated the answer...

Comment: Sorry just another thing, do you know how to adjust the speed of the slider too? What code would I need to add?

Comment: You can find all the options for the Nivo Slider here: http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider#jumpNav-5